# L1 activity regularization and L12 activity regularization with tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

How can I implement L1 activity regularization and L12 activity regularization with tensorflow (without keras)?

Answer (score 0):

Something in those lines might work using a lambda function
Inspired from:https://towardsdatascience.com/ridge-and-lasso-regression-a-complete-guide-with-python-scikit-learn-e20e34bcbf0b

Lasso: also known as L1 regularization

Ridge: also known as L2 regularization

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge

    def l1_regularization(x):
    ...
    Lasso (x)
    ...return x

    def l2_regularization(x):
    ...
    Lasso (x)
    ...
    return x

    model = Sequential()
    ...
    model.add(Lambda(lambda x: l1_regularization(x,axis=1)))
    ...
    model.add(Lambda(lambda x: l2_regularization(x,axis=1)))
    ...
    model.summary
```

Comment: In neural networks I can use : hidden = tf.layers.dense(X, n_hidden, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid,  activity_regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l1_regularizer(10e-3))